# Разместить файлы на веб-сервер nginx

Tags: сервер, nginx

Можно ли разместить файлы с помощью nginx, чтобы их потом можно было получить по ссылке или увидеть с помощью браузера? Например, ключи ssh. Или лучше поднять ftp?

Comment: что простите? вы хотите веб-сервером делать файл трансфер?

Comment: Ну, вообще-то это и есть основное предназначение веб-сервера в целом и nginx в частности, читайте документацию